# Cant figure out what value im extracting from website

Tags: java, android

Hey when I download some data from an website with jsoup he downloads some data but the problem is that some of that data , for some reason is a string that I can't identify. It's something like this :  " " . 
My problem is that I have already tested a million ways and I can't figure out what that blank space is. I can't find it when I take the data from the website, and change it to a String with the value  "N/A" or something. My problem is that I need those values to pass them into a float and I have a code that says if the value of those values is : "N/A"  don't pass it to a float! The problem is that I can't either pass that blank space to a float or transform it to an string with the value of : "N/A" !

Here is the data that I've downloaded from the website with jsoup among them you will find that blank space that I've told you about :

```
   08-28 12:28:21.236 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 111,9
   08-28 12:28:21.381 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 117,6
   08-28 12:28:21.535 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 139,8
   08-28 12:28:21.698 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 135,0
   08-28 12:28:21.859 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 141,5
   08-28 12:28:22.015 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 114,7
   08-28 12:28:22.190 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 146,8
   08-28 12:28:22.472 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 141,2
   08-28 12:28:22.626 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 102,8
   08-28 12:28:23.299 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media:  
   08-28 12:28:23.512 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media:  
   08-28 12:28:23.739 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 125,7
   08-28 12:28:24.499 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 152,5
   08-28 12:28:24.685 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 148,5
   08-28 12:28:24.852 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 123,0
   08-28 12:28:24.998 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 107,4
   08-28 12:28:25.271 18686-18742/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 113,4
   08-28 12:32:30.938 22455-22626/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 111,9
   08-28 12:32:31.080 22455-22626/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 117,6
   08-28 12:32:31.249 22455-22626/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/media: 139,8
```

Here is the code that I use to extract the data :

```
     try  {

        String site1 = "http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/indcurso.asp?letra=";
        Document document;

        Elements lista;

        document = Jsoup.connect(site1 +letra_value).get();

        Elements boxes = document.select("div.box10");


        for (Element box : boxes) {

            String linAreaC1 = box.select(".lin-area-c1").text();
            String linAreaC2 = box.select(".lin-area-c2").text();
            String linAreaC3 = box.select(".lin-area-c3").text();

            codigoCurso.add(linAreaC1);
            curso.add(linAreaC2);


            Element linCurso = box.nextElementSibling();

            while (linCurso.hasClass("lin-curso")) {
                String linCursoC2 = linCurso.select(".lin-curso-c2").text();
                String linCursoC3 = linCurso.select(".lin-curso-c3").text();
                String linCursoC4 = linCurso.select(".lin-curso-c4").text();


                codigoFaculdade.add(linCursoC2);
                faculades.add(linCursoC3);

                linCurso = linCurso.nextElementSibling();
            }
            faculades_main.add(faculades);
            faculades = new ArrayList<String>();
            codigosFaculdade.add(codigoFaculdade);
            codigoFaculdade= new ArrayList<String>();
        }


        for(int contador=0;contador<faculades_main.size();contador++){
            String codigoFaculdadi;
            String codigoCursi;


            codigoCursi = codigoCurso.get(contador);


            for(int i=0;i<codigosFaculdade.get(contador).size();i++){
                codigoFaculdadi=codigosFaculdade.get(contador).get(i);
                String site = "http://www.dges.gov.pt/guias/detcursopi.asp?codc="+codigoCursi+"&code="+codigoFaculdadi;
                Document document1 = Jsoup.connect(site).get();

                Elements media = document1.select(".tvag");




                if(media.size()!=0){
                    Log.d("media",(media.get(media.size()-1).text());
                    //Here is where I log the value
                    if(media.get(media.size()-1).text().equals(null)){
                        medias_to_add.add("N/A");
                    }else{
                    medias_to_add.add(media.get(media.size()-1).text());}
                }else {
                    medias_to_add.add("N/A");
                }

            }
            medias.add(medias_to_add);
            medias_to_add = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
```

Comment: If the tag is empty then dont use it. Or consider it 0,0. Or -1,0;

Comment: You should be abe to look in the source and find those empty tags (or attributes).

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: About what? Come to the point please.

Comment: How can I figure out whats that blank space , or whats its value ?

Comment: I already told you what you have to do for that.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for your help !